# Get current/previous commands with posix/bash (to set terminal emulator title to current command and re run them)

Tags: linux, terminal, posix

I'm running Alpine Linux 3.something thus mostly constricted to posix tooling

While I know how to set the title with escape sequences and can do so with `tput tsl` I don't know how to get the current command to display as the title, I'm bothered by seeing `.bashrc (~) - NVIM` when I'm most certainly not editing files and I like seeing what which terminal is doing/what is the working directory

<strike>And certain commands I'm used to from Arch/Debian flavas like `!!` are not available meaning if I forget to `doas`, I have to go up a line and hold `left` key a while.</strike> scratch that, it now works *somehow*

how to get the running/previous commands with only posix tools

Comment: The question is tagged `bash` and `.bashrc` appears in it, still Bash is not specified by POSIX and you probably don't use full-featured Bash as your shell (if you did then I guess `!!` would work). What do you use? What are you willing to use? Can you use Bash?

Comment: aight, by default it'd be `ash`, I changed that to `bash` 'cause `ash` wouldn't autosource a dotrc file 'cept `!!` _doesn't_ work, hence asking how to get the current & last command to regain features like `!!` and auto setting title for a terminal.

scratch that, I'll elaborate on further findings in my question